# Align a table in Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a table in my view and the values are not aligned. The first row is perfectly aligned, however the others are not. It seems like they are moving to right after each interaction.

[Table's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCKU4.jpg)

This is the view's code:

```
@model Dictionary<Especializacao, List<Consulta>>

   @{

    ViewData["Title"] = "Busca Agrupada";
    DateTime minDate = DateTime.Parse(ViewData["minDate"] as string);
    DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Parse(ViewData["maxDate"] as string);

}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="minDate">Min Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="minDate" value=@ViewData["minDate"]>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="maxDate">Max Date</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="maxDate" value=@ViewData["maxDate"]>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

@foreach (var especialGroup in Model)
{
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading bg-primary">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Especialização: @especialGroup.Key.Nome, Total: @especialGroup.Key.TotalDeConsultas(minDate, maxDate)</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <th>
                            Data
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Valor
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Doutor
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in especialGroup.Value)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Valor)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doutor.Nome)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Everything seems to be ok with the code.

Comment: This is because each "row" is in a separate table. If all the rows were in the same table then the columns would align. To get yours to align correctly I would suggest using fixed column widths - it looks like you maybe using Bootstrap so I think this is possible using the grid system (e.g. col-2, col-4, col-6).

Comment: @PeterG I've add them and now it's working like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by applying those lines:

```
 <thead>
                    <tr class="success">
                        <th class="col-lg-2">
                            Data
                        </th>
                        <th class="col-lg-2">
                            Valor
                        </th>
                        <th class="col-lg-2">
                            Doutor
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

```
                   <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in especialGroup.Value)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-lg-2">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-lg-2">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Valor)
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-lg-2">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.Doutor.Nome)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).